# How to create a DatagridTemplateColumn with checkbox and binding to a datasouce?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

Apologies in advance if I'm overlooking something - I'm still finding my feet working with Xaml rather than windows forms.

I'm trying to bind a data source to a DataGrid where one of the columns is a checkbox. My original solution worked fine for this, but required the user to double click the checkbox:

```
<Window x:Class="ExecBoxInvoices.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="507" Width="676">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,51">
    <DataGrid x:Name="InvoiceDG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="165" Margin="134,251,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Generate" Binding="{Binding Generate}" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table_Number" Binding="{Binding Table_Number}" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction_Date" Binding="{Binding Transaction_Date}" Width="175"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction_ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Transaction_ID}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The new solution for single click checkboxes is displayed below, but doesn't work (error is shown on the *Binding="{Binding Generate}"*):

```
<Window x:Class="ExecBoxInvoices.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="507" Width="676">
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,51">
    <DataGrid x:Name="InvoiceDG" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="165" Margin="134,251,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Generate" Width="60" Binding="{Binding Generate}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Table_Number" Binding="{Binding Table_Number}" Width="120"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction_Date" Binding="{Binding Transaction_Date}" Width="175"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Transaction_ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Transaction_ID}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

For reference, the code used to set the source is:

```
InvoiceDG.ItemsSource = recordCollection;
```

Where recordCollection is a list of:

```
class InvoiceRow
{
    public bool Generate { get; set; }
    public string Table_Number { get; set; }
    public string Transaction_Date { get; set; }
    public string Transaction_ID { get; set; }

    public InvoiceRow(bool generate, string table_Number, string transaction_Date, string transaction_ID)
    {
        this.Generate = generate;
        this.Table_Number = table_Number;
        this.Transaction_Date = transaction_Date;
        this.Transaction_ID = transaction_ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which flavor of XAML? Are you writing a desktop or a phone app? WPF, Silverlight, or Windows Store app (WinRT)?

Comment: desktop app, WPF (visual studio 2012)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Generate" Width="60">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Generate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: This code compiles, and creates a single click checkbox, but doesn't reflect changes back to the data source sadly :( I've updated original post to show where data source is set.

Comment: Use UpdateSourceTrigger: <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Generate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: Shouldn't it be "{Binding Generate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: OMG this just ended hours of mindless trial and error for me. Thank you! But why is the UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged necessary? It's not necessary for normal checkboxes.